# Error: The method convertProspectIds(Map<String,String>) in the type CompassADFAdaptor is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary

First, my apologies as I am a brand new Java developer and have been tasked to work on a massive application, so I am very out of my league.

I currently have this code.  Basically, it looks for some values on the URL of a web application, and then passes the name of the URL variable and the value of the URL variable into the application, where it will then be added to an output stream of text.  So the variables would look like "&LeadID=123" which would translate to the "LeadId" and "123".  At that point, we reformat it into an XML value, such as

```
<id sequence="1" source="leadId">123</id>
```

This is the code that is responsible for checking for the variables, and then putting them into a Map, and then (in theory) passing them to the code which will format them:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> ProspectTrackingKeys = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if (recipSettings.containsKey("leadId")) {
        ProspectTrackingKeys.put("LeadId", recipSettings.get("leadId"));
    }

    if (recipSettings.containsKey("wtk")) {
        ProspectTrackingKeys.put("wtk", recipSettings.get("wtk"));
    }

    if (recipSettings.containsKey("efd")) {
        ProspectTrackingKeys.put("efd", recipSettings.get("efd"));
    }

    if (recipSettings.containsKey("aid")) {
        ProspectTrackingKeys.put("aid", recipSettings.get("aid"));
    }

    if (recipSettings.containsKey("oth")) {
        ProspectTrackingKeys.put("oth", recipSettings.get("oth"));
    }
    list.add(ProspectTrackingKeys);


    prospect.setProspect(adaptor.convertProspectIds((Map<String, String>) prospectIds));
```

However, the last line of code (above) is generating these errors:

1. The method setProspect(ArrayList) is undefined for the type Prospect
2. The method convertProspectIds(Map) in the type CompassADFAdaptor is not applicable for the arguments (List)

This is in reference to this code, which is where the values should be passed into, and then formatted as the XML text:

```
public ArrayList<ProspectId> convertProspectIds(
            Map<String, String> recipientSettings) {
                ArrayList<ProspectId> prospectIdList = new ArrayList<ProspectId>();     

                int i = 0; 
                Iterator it = recipientSettings.entrySet().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    ProspectId Id = new ProspectId();
                    Id.setSequence(i++);
                    Id.setSource(ProspectIdSource.valueOf(pairs.getKey().toString()));
                    Id.setValue(pairs.getValue().toString());
                    prospectIdList.add(Id);
                }

                return prospectIdList;
    }
```

I am not quite sure what I am missing ... can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

`convertProspectIds` takes `Map` as an argument and you are passing it a `List`. You need to either change the method signature or convert `List` to `Map`.

The same goes for `setProspect` method. It does not expect `ArrayList` as a parameter.

Comment: I apologize, but I just don't quite understand how to change that.  Assuming I need to pass the map, so I have the Key and Value pair, what do I change?

Comment: Whats is in prospectIds. Is it a list of Strings?

Comment: It will be a set of key values, like:

    wtk,123
    aid,456
    efd,789

etc.